# Django missing argument from url > view

Tags: python, django

I currently receive this error when attempting to go the the url .../polls/products/

```
TypeError at /polls/products/

productindex() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I have tested the url attached to a view that I am sure works and it is fine, so I'm guessing there is something wrong with my view.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name

class Image(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
```

views.py

```
def productindex(request, product_image_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_image_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/products.html', {'product': product})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'products/$', views.productindex, name='productindex'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The view is expecting `request` and a product pk. Right now it is getting the request but not the pk.

Here is one way to pass the product.pk to the view.

urls.py...

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.productindex, name='productindex'),
)
```

and your html should look like this...

```
<a href="{% url 'productindex' product.pk %}">{{ product }}</a>
```